# call an external js file's function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to print time in html file using an `external` js file, but not able to print the time. If i use external js as inline than it print the time. Why so?

**My source code:**

```js
time(){
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday ", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
document.writeln("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
var hour = today.getHours();
var minute = today.getMinutes();
var second = today.getSeconds();
var prepand = (hour >= 12) ? " PM " : " AM ";
hour = (hour >= 12) ? hour - 12 : hour;
if (hour === 0 && prepand === ' PM ')
{
    if (minute === 0 && second === 0)
    {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' Noon';
    }
    else
    {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' PM';
    }
}
if (hour === 0 && prepand === ' AM ')
{
    if (minute === 0 && second === 0)
    {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' Midnight';
    }
    else
    {
        hour = 12;
        prepand = ' AM';
    }
}

document.write("Current Time : " + hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="watchdiv.css">
 
  <title>JavaScript current day and time</title>  
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="watch">
 <script src="watch.js">time()</script>
  
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What i missing to get result? in div tag no result print

Comment: `<script src="watch.js">time()</script>`, code between script tags will not be executed if there is a src attribute. It has to be one or the other. Also your code has syntax errors, take a look at your Developer's tools console

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely becuase the file does not load in-time and thus the script block that calls the time function fails.

Move the script tag that loads the file to the bottom of your html file. Ideally you should use some code logic that detects when the file is loaded. If you use a library like [jquery](https://jquery.com/) this has just that pre-installed.

You are also doing this wrong, you need two tags one loads the script one runs your function.

```
<script src="watch.js"></script>
<script>time();</script>
```

Comment: _"becuase the file does not load in-time and thus the script block that calls the time function fails."_ Load in time for what? Nothing was calling the code before their ill formed script tag.

Comment: I was trying to softly hint that ideally you should run your native code in the html doc after you know for sure that your files have loaded. Since if they add more files get more complex things will break. Thus i did it round back to front. Since the issue was a simple one.

Comment: Open console do you see an error. Either you have errors in the file or the file did not load in time.

Comment: if i remove the function in js file and than calling the js file in html as <div id="watch"><script src="watch.js"></script></div> then it works for me. i am beginner in js so plz help me about the function use.

Comment: OK, i don't understand. Can you tell me if you had an error in console?

Comment: in the file you have time() {... the code } it should read function time(){.. } as i said you have a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script src="watch.js"></script>
<script>time();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

datestmp.js:

```
date()
function date(){
test = new Date()
month = test.getMonth()
month = (month * 1) + 1
day = test.getDate()
year = test.getFullYear()
document.write(" ",month,"/",day,"/",year," ")
}
```

In Your HTML:

```
<script src="datestmp.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing loading and executing both at same time.

Since `Javascript` is synchronous. So, first you have to load file and next script tag would be execution code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="watch.js"></script>

<script>
   time();
</script>
```